# C++ Simple GUI for Windows, Linux and Mac

Tags: c++

I am looking for a simple gui for C++ program.It will be you used for a simple project & must be in file without dll and stuff like that.And must run on Windows,Linux and Mac.

Excuse my English.I am doing my best.

Comment: What are you asking for, exactly? Recommendations for a GUI framework, like Qt, or are you soliciting bids for UI development?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for shopping around for libraries, and even if it were your requirements are so generic that virtually anything would work.

Comment: Well I guess you can go for eclipse IDE for c/cpp developer. Of course there're many out there.

Answer (score 5):

QT   http://qt-project.org/downloads

Runs on Windows, Linux and Mac.

Sample QT code:

```
#include <QApplication>
 #include <QPushButton>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);

     QPushButton hello("Hello world!");
     hello.resize(100, 30);

     hello.show();
     return app.exec();
 }
```

More:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/3.3/tutorial1-01.html

http://linux301.wordpress.com/2009/06/15/hello-world-with-qt/

http://www.greyc.ensicaen.fr/ensicaen/Docs/Qt4/tutorial-t1.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [WxWidgets library](http://www.wxwidgets.org/). You should definitely look it up.

It runs on windows, Linux and mac.